# Is there any way to run Addressbook only from Outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office, addressbook

I'd like to run the Addressbook only(standalone) without running MS Office Outlook.
Is there any way to do it? or is there any alternative to run standalone.

I more often use Addressbook more than Outlook itself.
Therefore I'd like to run it handy.

to help understand, I attached a image of addressbook, not contacts.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do a shortcut directly on your desktop like in this question:
https://superuser.com/questions/714211/how-to-create-shortcut-that-opens-outlook-pab-file-personal-address-book

In the path:
*"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE16\OUTLOOK.EXE"  /select outlook:contacts*

Comment: It is very helpful by itself, to make up my question, I add the screenshot of address book.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook: `File | Options | Advanced | Outlook start and exit`. Select Contacts folder.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. The best what you can do is to choose a folder to open in Outlook at startup. See previous answers for more information.

As a workaround, you may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. It doesn't provide UI for displaying the data from the address book but allows to retrieve all the required information. Read more about that in the [Accessing the Address Book Data Using MAPI](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/miscellanious/article.php/c8479/Accessing-the-Address-Book-Data-Using-MAPI.htm) article.